# How Can I Make XPerf Write To Alternative Disk

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory-leaks

Last time I used XPerf it killed my SSD, too much disk activity.

Is there an easy way to make XPerf write its trace data to an alternative hard drive?

I am using the script HeapMonitor.cmd to start up XPerf, so I am guessing there are some command line options for XPerf that will do what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the answer is simply to move the HeapMonitor.cmd file to the other hard drive (non SSD) and it will just work.

There are command line options which look like this,

```
-f heap.etl
```

which could be changed to

```
-f f:\blah\heap.etl
```

I have done some of them, but not all of them, and it still seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but maybe you can work it out with a combination of absolute paths for ProfileFileName in -start and MergedETL in -stop -d ?

[Here's a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the command line parameter help.